# Как добавить элемент в конец коллекции Dictionary<String, MyClass>?

Tags: c#, словари

Столкнулся с одной проблемой. Есть свойство (коллекция) `Dictionary<String, MyClass> MyDic` и периодически запускается метод AddValues(), который добавляет в нее элементы. Самый первый раз элементы добавляются по порядку, но последующие разы - добавляются в самое начало. У меня два вопроса - почему не добавляются элементы в конец коллекции и можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Наверное потому что это словарь и очередность элементов в нем не гарантируется. С чего вы вообще взяли, что у словаря есть начало и конец?

Comment: Да ни с чего, был такой домысел.

Comment: Для моей задачи нужен список с уникальными значениями и чтобы в элементах был строгий порядок добавления в конец. Может подскажешь, что подойдет?

Comment: ну сделай свою коллекцию на основе словаря и списка, то есть добавляй с список и в словарь элемент только тогда, когда его ещё нет в словаре, а для получения набора элементов используй проход по списку

Comment: спасибо, но я решил проблему по другому. Вариант - и список и коллекция мне не подходит.

Comment: по другому - это как?

Comment: Из комментариев стало понятно одно требование к коллекции: элементы должны идти в том порядке, в котором были добавлены. А каковы другие требования? Как нужно получать элементы: по ключу, по индексу, как-то ещё? Каковы требования к другим операциям: удаление, вставка в середину/начало?

Comment: добавление только в конец, в середину и в начало - не нужно, да есть и нужно удаление по ключу и обращение к элементу по ключу. Коллекция подразумевает уникальность

Comment: инициализирую временную коллекцию, добавляю в нее элементы, а потом объединяю элементы коллекций с помощью Union - вот так решил проблему

Answer (score 1):

Элементы не добавляются в конец, потому что класс `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` реализован как хэш-таблица. Порядок элементов в хэш-таблице может быть произвольным.

Чтобы управлять порядком элементов, используйте класс [`SordtedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2). Он реализован на базе сбалансированного двоичного дерева.

Имейте в виде, что операции вставки, удаления и поиска элемента по ключу в двоичном дереве имеют сложность *O(log N)* против *O(1)* у хэш-таблицы.

Comment: В общем, использую SortedDictionary, но при добавлении элементов элементы добавляются первый раз по порядку, затем я удаляю все элементы по по ключу и во второй раз, при добавлении элементов - добавление идет в конец.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, как ты определяешь добавился элемент в начало или в конец?

Comment: при переборе элементов

Comment: после первого добавления элементов я перебираю элементы и они идут по порядку. После второго добавления элементов - делаю перебор и она в обратном порядке

Comment: SortedDictionary - все элементы отсортированы по ключу, а мне нужно,чтобы элементы были в той последовательности, в которой я добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Пример как скрестить 2 коллекции

```
public class MyAwesomeCollection<TK, TV> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TK, TV>>
{
    private List<TK> _listItems = new List<TK>();
    private Dictionary<TK, TV> _dictItems = new Dictionary<TK, TV>();


    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TK, TV>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _listItems.Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<TK, TV>(x,_dictItems[x])).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void AddToEnd(TK key, TV value)
    {
        if (_dictItems.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _dictItems[key] = value;
            _listItems.Remove(key);
            _listItems.Add(key);
        }
        else 
        {   _dictItems[key] = value;
            _listItems.Add(key);
        }
    }

    public void CLear()
    {
        _dictItems.Clear();
        _listItems.Clear();
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var coll = new MyAwesomeCollection<int,int>();
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    coll.AddToEnd(i, i+i);      
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, возможно это классное решение. Как по мне, то уже лучше создать свой класс для хранения данных

Comment: @АлександрПузанов `Как по мне, то уже лучше создать свой класс для хранения данных` так я это и сделал :)

Comment: я понял, это комментарий